# Xcode 7.1 beta tab bar item image too big

Tags: xcode

Copied PNG image in 2x as shown.
[image: Assets.cassets]

Referred image in storyboard as shown

[image]

But display in the tab bar item is too big as shown

[image: tab bar item]

Can someone tell me why the image is not fitting inside the tab bar?

Comment: What size is that image? And why are you using Xcode 7.1 Beta?

Comment: size: 404x404 px, 90 pixels/inch. Used inkscape to create the image. I am using x-code Beta because it is latest. Is there a problem with it?

Comment: The current version of Xcode (not x-code) is 7.3.1. There is currently no beta for a newer version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`404x404` is too large of an image for a tab bar. The images don't scale, so you need to include the correct size image. The images need to be 30x30 points. That means 30x30 pixels for the @1x version, 60x60 pixels for the @2x version, and 90x90 for the @3x version.

Comment: Thank you the size worked. But my tab bar image when selected in iPhone, does not get highlighted. I did create image using Inkscape with alpha channel set to zero. What could be wrong?

Comment: Probably better to ask another question, and post the image file as well so we can check the format etc. (Also, please don't forget to up vote the answer if it helped you).

Comment: To solve the selected image problem, try to set the Selected Image on Tab Bar Item section (on the right tab).